# What is the best way to handle multiple h2o api calls for training algorithms in production?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, h2o

I'm trying to build a web app which lets users to upload a data set , select an h2o algorithm of their choice and train their data set to build a model.
Now, if multiple users will hit the server simultaneously, h2o starts processing the requests( starts training the models) parallelly. This increases the training time for all the users.
So, what is the best way in which I should use h2o in this scenario?
Should I keep those requests in a queue and execute them one by one? (this will add a waiting time for a new user)

[I ran a GLM model for classification on a 50 MB structured and clean data set. It took almost twice the time when I executed two api calls simultaenously (model 1 and 2) than when I ran it individually (model 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFWFK.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would queue them.

Additionally, I would restart the H2O cluster from scratch each time.

Finally, I would drive the H2O cluster from python or R.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom for your answer. I did a small poc on the same and found that if total underlying resources (CPU and RAM) are fixed, executing requests sequentially would perform better.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends mostly on how you want your user experience to be -- whether or not you are okay with users waiting, or if you'd rather have all users slowed down.  If it's a free service, then I think users would expect to wait.  I agree with Tom that it's probably better to queue the jobs, though it's a personal design/user experience choice.

If you run the jobs in parallel, I'd recommend starting each H2O instance (one per user) on a different port.  These sessions will still share (compete for) resources if running on the same machine, but at least it's a bit cleaner (they can't overwrite each other's models, etc).

Comment: How are you doing in H2o driverless ai. Are you running models in parallel or sequentially. I just ran few data sets using your 21 days evaluation version and that was fast considering it ran quite a few models.

Comment: Thanks a lot Erin for your answer. I did a small poc on the same and found that if total underlying resources (CPU and RAM) are fixed, executing requests sequentially would perform better.